# Using windows phone combined motion api to track device position

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'd like to track the position of the device with respect to an initial position with high accuracy (ideally) for motions at a small scale (say < 1 meter). The best bet seems to be using motionReading.SensorReading.DeviceAcceleration. I tried this. But ran into few problems. Apart from the noisy readings (which I was expecting and can tolerate), I see some behaviors that are conceptually wrong - e.g. If I start from rest, move the phone around and bring it back to rest- and in the process periodically update the velocity vector along all the dimensions, I would expect the magnitude of the velocity to be very small (ideally 0). But I don't see that. I have extensively reviewed available help including the official msdn pages but I don't see any examples where the position/velocity of the device are updated using the acceleration vector. Is the acceleration vector that the api returns (atleast in theory) supposed to be the rate of change of velocity or something else? (FYI - my device does not have a gyroscope, so the api is going to be the low accuracy version.)